# WPF: Add 5 Pixels to Column Width

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, converters

I have a Grid with 4 columns:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="14" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Now i want to add 5 Pixels to the width of the third column? Do i need a converter for this, or is there any other simple trick to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a converter, but before that, you can't TemplateBinding to ActualWidth.

Stuff will not work like you want it to, because the other columns will cause you control to resize itself.

You will need another solution